# Jest encountered an unexpected token: SyntaxError Unexpected token

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs, enzyme, babel-jest

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 1.53 GB / 11.63 GB
      Shell: 5.4.2 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.16.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.19.0 - /usr/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/npm
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: ^0.59.8 => 0.59.10
```

I have these configurations:

```
//babel.config.js

module.exports = {
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
};

//jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    preset: 'react-native',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-tests.js'],

};

//package.json

 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
```

And this is the error that I get:
[image: error]
I have read many github issues, but they were too old with previous versions of babel and jest , most of them had `.bablerc`. How can I solve this issue?